# Prevent a dllexport function defined in a static library from being exported from a higher-level DLL

Tags: c++, windows, dll, dllexport

I have a *static* library in which there is a function `void f()` declared with `__declspec(dllexport)`. This static .lib is linked to a DLL. Problem: this DLL ends up exporting `f()` (defined in the .lib) which is undesirable. Can this export be defeated?

It makes no matter if the forward declaration of `f()` in the DLL contains `__declspec(dllimport)` or if there is no export/import directive at all. `f()` is exported from the DLL either way.

Comment: Hmya, there is no "oops, didn't mean to do that" option.  Getting the linker to select another version of the function that you define in the DLL source could be an alternative.  But requires source to get it right so is chicken-and-egg.  Maybe /EXPORT with NONAME so it is only exported by ordinal might work, never tried it.

Comment: @HansPassant: If it is possible to export this function under a different name, or no name at all, that may well solve all my problems.

Comment: @RustyX: actually, the shared library does not see `f()` with `dllexport`, as explained in my question. Only the static library is compiled with `dllexport`.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say recompile the *static* library without `declspec(dllexport)` of course. The linker simply collects all `dllexport` declarations from every input file (.obj and .lib) and produces the export table in the final executable/DLL. There is no easy way around that.

Comment: I understand that you don't have the sources for the static lib (or if you have them you'd like to avoid changing them). But, do you have the header (if any) file for the static lib (and if yes, is it possible to modify it)?

Comment: @CristiFati: I do have the headers. I can modify them as long as I don't break anything. For instance, I can control the `export`/`import` attributes through macros and `#ifdef`s.

Comment: We're talking the case the function from the static lib is called in the dynamic lib, otherwise the linker would ignore it when building the dynamic lib. The [\[MSDN\]: /EXPORT (Exports a Function)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/export-exports-a-function) (with *NONAME*) works indeed (the func is only exported by ordinal).